# Ony use css to move the nav bar to the right in this layout?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to see if it is possible that only using CSS, we can get this.

The HTML is like (I will simply use class name here to illustrate it):

```
<body-wrapper>

<logo>
</logo>

<nav>
</nav>

<content>
</content>

<footer>
</footer>

</body-wrapper>
```

The desired final UI layout should be:

```
|--------------------|
|      logo          |
|--------------------|
|              |     |
|    content   | nav |
|              |     |
|              |     |
|--------------|     |
|     footer   |     |
|              |     |
|--------------|-----|
```

Note we don't know the exact height of the logo section.

I couldn't figure out how to make this happen (or whether it is possible or not using only CSS).

Any idea?

Thanks!
(PS, if I were able to put a wrapper div that covers nav, content, and footer, then it will be easy to do that. But the current HTML doesn't have that, and I want to see if we can make it work without changing the current HTML)

Comment: It will be much easier to just merge `content` and `footer` into a single `div` than having some hacky solution to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you say that you don't have access to the `html` DOM, So You can maybe do it as follows.

*PS: I know this is absurd, and whacky but we are working on a really edge case here guyz so no room for best practices here.* :)

```
.logo{
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
}
.nav{
  width:35%;
  float:right;
}
.content{
  width:65%;
  float:left;
}
.footer{
  width:65%;
  float:left;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf8op73j/)**

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. By the way, I guess in this case we don't need to float the .logo, right?

Comment: No, In order to break the normal HTML flow, we need to float the `<logo>` Otherwise it wont occupy the 100% of the width, you can try it out in the jsfiddle.